# Robust way to parse an image of a table

Tags: parsing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

What is a good way to parse an image of a table? I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969091/processing-an-image-of-a-table-to-get-data-from-it) that is counting the number of x's in the table but it relies on having an image of x to search with.

Here is an example image of a table I would like to parse:

[image]

In my case the data would be mostly numbers. How can I extract cells from the table image so that there are separate images for each cell that can be used for OCR and a correct order of data? Does some sort of machine learning solution exist, rather than computer vision?

By robust I mean:

- Works with different cell backgrounds
- Does not fail with thicker or thinner outlines, or no outlines at all
- Works with different spacing between columns / rows

Comment: In case you are open for it, I think the simplest way would be to try some custom object detection API like http://app.nanonets.com/ObjectCategorySelection/

Comment: And match text? I guess I will try

Comment: solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452222/detect-table-with-opencv/46806306#46806306  might be helpful with some small tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

The [OCR API](https://ocr.space/) seems to offer some table-related functionality. I just found it, so I have no further insight, but you might want to check it out. You can do an online test, where you can check the following box

```
Do receipt scanning and/or table recognition
```

My results were okay. Single letters weren't found but overall text and numbers were recognized.